# Validating integer values in C

Tags: c

I've documented the program specifications in the comment block located at the top. In the function displayNameByValue, I'm passing in an integer variable called passValue that stores the number of times the user's name will be displayed to the console. I want to be able to account for user input error and validate for any input the user passes in that's not represented by an integer. What's the best possible solution to handle this situation?

Here's my code :

```
/*******************************************************************************
 Concept:
         1.) Display the Programmer's Name
         2.) Display the Programmer's Name Again
         3.) Display the Programmer's Name X Times
         4.) Display a Triangle of an Entered Character
         5.) Exit the Program 
*******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

char displayMenu();
void displayName(char *userName);
void displayNameAgain(char *userName);
int displayNameByValue(char *userName, int passValue);

char *userName = "Demetrius \n";

int main()
{
    char menuOption;
    int passValue = 0;

menuOption = displayMenu();
while(menuOption != 'E')
{
   switch(menuOption)
   {
     case 'A':
              displayName(userName);
              break;
     case 'B':
              displayNameAgain(userName);
              break;
     case 'C':
              displayNameByValue(userName, passValue);
              break;
     case 'D':
              // currently working @ the moment...
              break;
     default:
              printf("You've entered an invalid character entry! \n\n");
              break;
    }
              menuOption = displayMenu();
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}

char displayMenu()
{
char menuChoice;

printf("**********************************************************\n");
printf("A. Display the Programmer's Name                         *\n");
printf("B. Display the Programmer's Name Again                   *\n");
printf("C. Display the Programmer's Name X times                 *\n");
printf("D. Display a Triangle of an Entered Character            *\n");
printf("E. Exit the Program                                      *\n");
printf("**********************************************************\n\n");

printf("Enter a character that corresponds to the menu above :\n");
scanf("%s", &menuChoice);

menuChoice = toupper(menuChoice); // Assigns all menu submissions to uppercase 

return menuChoice;
}

void displayName(char *userName)
{
 printf("%s", userName);
}

void displayNameAgain(char *userName)
{
 printf("The programmer's name is : %s" , userName);
}

int displayNameByValue(char *userName, int passValue)
{
int index;

printf("Enter the number of times to display your name :");
scanf("%d", &passValue);


for(index = 0; index < passValue; index++)
{
          printf("%s\n", userName);
}

printf("Your name was displayed : %d times\n", index);

return passValue;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! I'm not asking for you to solve the solution, I would like to know what's the best direction. I originally wrote a conditional testing the limits of an integer by using INT_MIN and INT_MAX, but that only tests the range of an integer. The program specifications didn't include anything about error detection, so this is a question that only concerns me, not the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the parameter `int passValue` is, well, an integer it will ALWAYS (by definition) be somewhere in the range  INT_MIN to INT_MAX.

If you are instead interested in making sure the value is in a narrower range (say at least 1 and less than 100), you could define constants in your program for the MIN_ACCEPTABLE and MAX_ACCEPTABLE values, and test like

```
if (passValue < MIN_ACCEPTABLE || passValue > MAX_ACCEPTABLE)
{
    // Report the error somehow
}
```

The function as written does not allow for "bad" (as in non-integer) input because the parameter is of type integer.

If your intent is to convert a `char *` to an int, have a look at [strtol](http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-strtol).

Comment: Narrowing the range is definitely something I would be interested in testing, and that would limit the integer value to a set limit and then I could have a continue under the print statement within that conditional to continue the user to input a valid integer. I've noticed the compiler crashes if the input is anything other than an integer. How can I test this?

Comment: What do you mean "the compiler crashes"?  You do something like `int passValue = "Yada yada";`?  If that's the case, there's nothing your program can do or test.  The compiler is just doing its job telling you that you have invalid C syntax.

Comment: I apologize for not wording that correctly, a few minutes ago I entered in a value that wasn't an integer and the compiler exited. I think I'm going to keep it simple and have a set limit like you've described above to minimize any user complications.